# I have Method addSeconds does not exist error under docker

Tags: docker, laravel-5, php-carbon

I try to install my laravel 5.5 / postgres app under docker and I encountered error:

```
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
```

To fix it in composer.json file I added line :

```
"nesbot/carbon": "2 as 1.24.1"
```

so composer.json has :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
        "graham-campbell/markdown": "^8.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "khill/lavacharts": "3.0.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "nesbot/carbon": "2 as 1.24.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "stolz/laravel-html-tidy": "^0.1.1",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0",
        "filp/whoops" : "~2.0" 
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\": "Modules/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],

        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]

    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

After that running my app I got error :

```
[2019-11-11 08:31:40] local.ERROR: Method addSeconds does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method addSeconds does not exist. at /var/www/lprods_docker_root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:96)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/lprods_docker_root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/InteractsWithTime.php(37): Illuminate\\Support\\Carbon->__call('addSeconds', Array)
```

and I see that addSeconds in used several times under vendor/ directory.

Is it version issue ? How to fix it ?

```
# php artisan --version        
Laravel Framework 5.5.44
```

Comment: try running `composer update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like decision with :

```
 "nesbot/carbon": "2 as 1.24.1"
```

was invalid.
I installed composer with command :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
composer update
```

and run after :

```
  ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon
```

it works ok!